# best way to loop calculations in php

Tags: php, html

i want to calculate two operations with the help of loop. They are already working and providing result i need. But i want them to look more like coding. So if anybody can help them with the help of **for in php**

```
for($i=0;i<something;$i++){
    $temp_calc = ;
}
```

---

here are two statements.

1. In first statement length of array is 9.
2. In second statement length of array is 12.

both statements to be solved in different for loop as they are totally different questions.

---

```
$temp_calc = 10*$temp_array[0]+9*$temp_array[1]+8*$temp_array[2]+7*$temp_array[3]+6*$temp_array[4]+5*$temp_array[5]+4*$temp_array[6]+3*$temp_array[7]+2*$temp_array[8];

$temp_calc = 1*$temp_array[0]+3*$temp_array[1]+1*$temp_array[2]+3*$temp_array[3]+1*$temp_array[4]+3*$temp_array[5]+1*$temp_array[6]+3*$temp_array[7]+1*$temp_array[8]+3*$temp_array[9]+1*$temp_array[10]+3*$temp_array[11];
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Where do your integer values come from - in your first calc, you have `10`, then `9`, etc. - where do those values come from? And in the second, you have `1`, `3`, `1`, `3` - which is a very different sequence.  What defines these values?

Comment: it's a arthematic operation , like multiply first digit by 10 second by 9 and so on.

both calculation are to be done in seperate loop and seperate answers

Comment: I understand that it's an arithmatic calculation, but what we need to know in order to help answer is **where** do the values come from? How are they defined / set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for both issues:

```
$temp_array = array(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2);//sample

function calc_1($temp_array){//first
    $total=0;
    $count = count($temp_array)+1;
    foreach($temp_array as $value){
        $total += $count*$value;
        $count-=1;
    }  
    return $total;
}
function calc_2($temp_array){//second
    $total=0;
    foreach($temp_array as $k=>$value){
        $total += ($k%2==0) ? 1*$value : 3*$value;//when is even or odd
    }  
    return $total;
}
var_dump(calc_1($temp_array));//resp1
var_dump(calc_2($temp_array));//resp2
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 2):

It will be a little simpler to use a `foreach` loop rather than a `for` loop. If you specifically need to use a `for` loop because it is a requirement of an assignment, you can check the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php). There are some examples there of using a `for` loop to loop over an array. This is a common and basic control structure and it will be more valuable for you to really understand how to use it. The more important part is what goes on inside the loop. There are multiple ways to do this, but here are some basic examples.

First one:

```
// initialize multiplier and result outside the loop
$multiplier = 10;
$result = 0;

// loop over the values
foreach ($temp_array as $value) {
    // add the value * multiplier to the result and decrement the multiplier
    $result += $value * $multiplier--;
}
```

Second one

```
// initialize multiplier and result outside the loop
$multiplier = 1;
$result = 0;

// loop over the values
foreach ($temp_array as $value) {
    // add the value * multiplier to the result
    $result += $value * $multiplier;
    // switch the multiplier to the alternating value
    if ($multiplier == 1) {
        $multiplier = 3;
    } else {
        $multiplier = 1;
    }
    // The switch can be done more simply using a ternary operator like this:
    // $multiplier = $multiplier == 1 ? 3 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your result

```
$temp_calc = 10*$temp_array[0]+9*$temp_array[1]+8*$temp_array[2]+7*$temp_array[3]+6*$temp_array[4]+5*$temp_array[5]+4*$temp_array[6]+3*$temp_array[7]+2*$temp_array[8];
```

You should have for loop as following. It will run the loop till 8th index of your `temp_array` and multiply each index value with `$i` and sum up in a variable `$temp_calc_1`.

```
<?php
$temp_calc_1 = 0;
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
    $temp_calc_1 = $temp_calc_1 + ( 10-$i)*$temp_array[$i] ;
}
```

For your second result

```
$temp_calc = 1*$temp_array[0]+3*$temp_array[1]+1*$temp_array[2]+3*$temp_array[3]+1*$temp_array[4]+3*$temp_array[5]+1*$temp_array[6]+3*$temp_array[7]+1*$temp_array[8]+3*$temp_array[9]+1*$temp_array[10]+3*$temp_array[11];
```

The above should be converted to the following loop, this will run loop till your 12th index of `temparray`and do the calculation. This time it will multiply each index value of `temparray` by either 1 and 3. So first time it will multiply with 1 and next time with 3 and so on

```
//
$temp_calc_2 = 0;
for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){
    $j = $i%2?3:1;
    $temp_calc_2 = $temp_calc_2 + $j*$temp_array[$i] ;
}
?>
```

Comment: you got it right the way i want but there is something wrong in it . page stops loading when using it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard does that appear to be better now :)

Answer (score 0):

If your array is called `$myArray`, then:

```
/*Since I can't know what the sequence of the values are that you
are multiplying, and because you might need other sequences in the
future, a function was developed that chooses which sequence you
want to multiply.*/

function findSomeValues($arraySize)
{
  switch ($arraySize) {
    case 9:
    {
      $someValues = array(10,9,8,7,4,5,4,3,2);
    }
    break;
    case 12:
    {
      $someValues = array(1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3);
    }
    break;
    default:
      $someValues = array();
  }

  return $someValues;
}

/*This following function then finds how big your array is, looks
for a sequence stored in the findSomeValues function. If a sequence
exist for that array size (in this case if you have an array either
9 or 12 elements long), the result will be calculated and echoed. If
the sequence was not found, an error message would be echoed.*/

function multiplyValues($myArray) {
  $result = 0;
  $arraySize = count($myArray);//obtaining array size
  $someValues = findSomeValues($arraySize);//obtaining sequence to multiply with
  if (count($someValues)>0)
  {
    for($i=0;i<$arraySize;$i++){
      $result += $myArray[i]*$someValues[i];
    }
    echo "result = ".$result."<br>";//result message
  }
  else
  {
    echo "you are missing some values<br>";//error message
  }
}
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

---

**Alternative:**

If you prefer something a bit simpler:

```
//this array holds the sequences you have saved:
$sequenceArray = array(
  9 => array(10,9,8,7,4,5,4,3,2),
  12 => array(1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3)
);

//this function does the multiplication:
function multiplyValues($myArray)
{
  $arraySize = count($myArray);
  for($i=0;i<$arraySize;$i++){
    $result += $myArray[i]*$sequenceArray[i];
  }
  echo "result = ".$result."<br>";//result message
}
```

Comment: can u write code like sammer, simple for loop. thnx for answer.

Comment: author of that second answer

Comment: @Shristi Yes, I added an alternative to my answer. Let me know if that works well for you